# Is spring-boot-configuration-processor dependency only for IDE support?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotation-processor

I just wanted to know what officially the `spring-boot-configuration-processor` dependency is for.

I use it in the dependencies, whom are used in a microservice and I want to have the autocompletion in order to manage my configurations. I can see the result in Spring Tool Suite autocompletion, it works fine, and it is useful.

Nevertheless, I wonder if there is another utility to that dependency. I can imagine a usage like dashboard or Spring Boot Admin where the configuration can be edited and it helps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata is consumed in various ways and I am not sure anyone has a full overview of all usages. The IDEs are the main consumers as this was designed for tooling in the first place.

The Spring Boot project consumes the metadata to auto-generate [the appendix that lists the keys](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/appendix.html#common-application-properties). I know that the Apache Camel does something similar.

There are also standalone editors for configuration that uses this (same use case as the IDE).